# Show tool-tip on links of force directed graph in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am working on a simple force directed graph as given in [This](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) link. It works well but I want to show tool-tip on edges also as it shows on nodes. Whenever I move the mouse on an edge, it shows some tool-tip on the link (data may be retrieved from JSON file). 
Is there a builtin method or I have to show the div on mouse-over (in this case how to get the position of mouse, where the div would be shown)

Comment: Refer here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1212197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there a builtin method?

**Ans**: Yes. There is a built in way. Most HTML elements support the title attribute. When you move the mouse pointer over that element, a little tool-tip is shown for a certain amount of time or until you leave that element.

**Demo:**

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 200

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var graph = {
  nodes: [{
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B'
  }],
  links: [{
    source: 0,
    target: 1
  }]
};

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .gravity(.05)
  .distance(100)
  .charge(-100)
  .size([w, h])
  .start();

var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("svg:line")
  .attr("class", "link");
link.append("title").text(function(d) {
  return d.source.name + " -> " + d.target.name
});

var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);
node.append("circle").attr("r", 5);
node.append("title").text(function(d) {
  return d.name
});


force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});
```

```css
line {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
cicrle {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

2. or I have to show the div on mouse-over? How to get the position of mouse? Where the div would be shown?

**Ans:**

If you would like to show a tooltip with html content, you can show a div on mouse-over. You can get the mouse position using `d3.mouse` method.

**Demo:**

```js
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var margin = 20;
var pad = margin / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();


var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Myriel",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Napoleon",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Mlle.Baptistine",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Magloire",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "CountessdeLo",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Geborand",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Champtercier",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Cravatte",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Count",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "OldMan",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Labarre",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Valjean",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Marguerite",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.deR",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Isabeau",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Gervais",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Tholomyes",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Listolier",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Fameuil",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Blacheville",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Favourite",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Dahlia",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Zephine",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Fantine",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Thenardier",
    "group": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Thenardier",
    "group": 4
  }, ],
  "links": [{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 5,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }]
};
drawGraph(graph);

function drawGraph(graph) {
  var svg = d3.select("#force").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // draw plot background
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "#eeeeee");

  // create an area within svg for plotting graph
  var plot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "plot")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", " + pad + ")");

  // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-force
  var layout = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width - margin, height - margin])
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(function(d, i) {
      return (d.source.group == d.target.group) ? 50 : 100;
    })
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

  drawLinks(graph.links);
  drawNodes(graph.nodes);

  // add ability to drag and update layout
  // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-drag
  d3.selectAll(".node").call(layout.drag);

  // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-on
  layout.on("tick", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    d3.selectAll(".node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  });
}

// Draws nodes on plot
function drawNodes(nodes) {
  // used to assign nodes color by group
  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-nodes
  d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d, i) {
      return 4;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.group);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {

      var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
      var tooltip = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("text")
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        //.attr("dy", -r * 2)
        .attr("id", "tooltip");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
      d3.select("#tooltip").remove();
    });
}

// Draws edges between nodes
function drawLinks(links) {
  var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links, function(d, i) {
      return d.value;
    }))
    .range([1, 6]);

  // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-links
  d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d, i) {
      return scale(d.value) + "px";
    })
    .style("stroke-dasharray", function(d, i) {
      return (d.value <= 1) ? "2, 2" : "none";
    }).on("mouseover", function(d, i) {

      var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
      var tooltip = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("text")
        .text(d.source.name + " -> " + d.target.name)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        //.attr("dy", -r * 2)
        .attr("id", "tooltip");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
      d3.select("#tooltip").remove();
    });

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
b {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #888888;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
#tooltip {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #000000;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}
.node {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-weight: 1px;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #888888;
  stroke-weight: 1px;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}
.highlight {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-weight: 4px;
  stroke-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="force"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<title>` element for `line` elements in the same way the linked demo does for `circle` elements. For instance,

```
link.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return "This is my title"; });
```

would create such tooltips in the demo linked. Note that, [according to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title), you should ensure the title element is the first child of the parent.

Also note that this may not be an effective way to communicate with the user; hovering over a line is rather difficult, especially in a moving graph. One potential solution would be to wrap each line in a larger group with an invisible line of larger width, and add the title as the first child of the group, as the title element also works just fine with `<g>` elements.

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet or explain in detail about the proposed solution to hovering the thin line.