# How to make mouseover functionality permanent

Tags: d3.js

I want to make a force graph with permanently visible text on the nodes and text on the links.

This [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/X5X34/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=X5X34) provides labels on the nodes.

The 2nd snippet from an answer to [Show tool-tip on links of force directed graph in d3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165265/show-tool-tip-on-links-of-force-directed-graph-in-d3js) provides mouseover labels on links and nodes.

I'm currently trying to extend the second to make the mouseover node labels permanent.

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 125;
var margin = 20;
var pad = margin / 2;

var graph = {  "nodes":[ { "name": "A"}, { "name": "B"}] };
drawGraph(graph);

function drawGraph(graph) {
  var svg = d3.select("#force").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // create an area within svg for plotting graph
  var plot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "plot")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", " + pad + ")");

  var layout = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width - margin, height - margin])
    .charge(-120)
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .start();

  drawNodes(graph.nodes);

  // add ability to drag and update layout
  d3.selectAll(".node").call(layout.drag);

  layout.on("tick", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".node")
      .attr("cx", d =>  { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", d =>  { return d.y; });
      
  });
}

// Draws nodes on plot
function drawNodes(nodes) {

  d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => { return d.name;  })
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => { return d.y;  })
    .attr("r",  4)
    .style("fill", "#EE77b4")
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {

      var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
      var tooltip = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("text")
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("id", "tooltip");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
      d3.select("#tooltip").remove();
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
b {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #888888;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
#tooltip {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #000000;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}
.node {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-weight: 1px;
}
.highlight {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-weight: 4px;
  stroke-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="force"></div>
```

I've tried replacing the mouseover function with:

```
.each( function(d, i) {
      var x = d.x; //d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var y = d.y; //d3.mouse(this)[1];
      var tooltip = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("text")
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("id", "tooltip");

    })
```

but now the labels don't move so I added

```
d3.selectAll("text").attr( "x", d => { return d.x; })
                    .attr( "y", d => { return d.y; });
```

in `layout.on("tick", function() ...`

But now it's all in one place doesn't move and I get `TypeError: d is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code this way (pay attention on the comments):

```
  layout.on("tick", function() {
    tooltips // here we set new position for tooltips on every tick
      .attr("x", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
      .attr("y", (d, i) => { return d.y;  });

    d3.selectAll(".node")
      .attr("cx", d =>  { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", d =>  { return d.y; });

  });

...

function drawNodes(nodes) {
  tooltips = d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => { return d.name;  })
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => { return d.y;  })
    .attr("r",  4)
    .style("fill", "#EE77b4")
    .select(function() { return this.parentNode }) // returns to parent node
    .append('text') // append svg-text elements for tooltip
    .data(nodes)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; }) // set text
    .attr("x", (d, i) => { return d.x;  }) // set initial x position
    .attr("y", (d, i) => { return d.y;  }) // set initial y position
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "tooltip-" + i; }) // set unique id
    .attr("class", "d3-tooltip");
}
```

Working demo:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 125;
var margin = 20;
var pad = margin / 2;
var tooltips = null;

var graph = {  "nodes":[ { "name": "A"}, { "name": "B"}] };
drawGraph(graph);

function drawGraph(graph) {
  var svg = d3.select("#force").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // create an area within svg for plotting graph
  var plot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "plot")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", " + pad + ")");

  var layout = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width - margin, height - margin])
    .charge(-120)
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .start();

  drawNodes(graph.nodes);

  // add ability to drag and update layout
  d3.selectAll(".node").call(layout.drag);

  layout.on("tick", function() {
    tooltips
      .attr("x", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
      .attr("y", (d, i) => { return d.y;  });
    
    d3.selectAll(".node")
      .attr("cx", d =>  { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", d =>  { return d.y; });
      
  });
}

// Draws nodes on plot
function drawNodes(nodes) {
  tooltips = d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => { return d.name;  })
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => { return d.y;  })
    .attr("r",  4)
    .style("fill", "#EE77b4")
    .select(function() { return this.parentNode })
    .append('text')
    .data(nodes)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("x", (d, i) => { return d.x;  })
    .attr("y", (d, i) => { return d.y;  })
    .attr("class", "d3-tooltip")
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "tooltip-" + i; });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
b {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #888888;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.d3-tooltip {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #000000;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}
.node {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-weight: 1px;
}
.highlight {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-weight: 4px;
  stroke-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="force"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I set the `font-family` for the `tooltip` only?
I tried moving the line from `body` to `#tooltip` but it didn't work...

Comment: @peer I updated the answer, check it. You can add "class" attribute for the tooltips (`d3-tooltip` in our case) and define styles for this class in your css.